# Heroku exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku showing this exception when try to restart server. this doesnt tells where the issue is exactly

```
2014-11-25T08:27:04.671821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668864+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668866+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668862+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668855+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-11-25 08:27:07] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668881+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668883+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668867+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668890+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-11-25 08:27:07] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668889+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-11-25 08:27:07] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-11-25T08:27:07.700009+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668875+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668873+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668876+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668878+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668869+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668870+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668872+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.700019+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-11-25T08:27:07.700021+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-11-25T08:27:07.668879+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-11-25T08:27:07.700016+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:8363
2014-11-25T08:27:07.700018+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-11-25T08:27:07.700022+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-11-25T08:27:07.113073+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
```

Comment: Which command you are using for restart the Heroku server ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks you try to restart server, but get a fatal error.

```
[2014-11-25 08:27:07] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
```

If your server works well before, try to restart server or contact your server administrator.

Heroku use Postgresql as database server, could you paste your migration here?

Comment: Yes this error occurring on restart or when I try to deploy. SIGTERM exception occuring when dyons shuts down so webrick gives this exception but I am not understanding why dyons not showing any details of exception. If i revert to previous commit it works fine. i have just added few migrations in new commit and did heroku rake db:migrate and this exception start occuring

Answer (score 0):

This issue was occurring due to some missing configurations in production.rb Heroku app started server  fine once those configrations added in production.rb